# Type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ShopInRelationshipModel> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a two class ShopModel and ShopInRelationshipModel and I received a nested response from supabase. Kindly help with how to convert that response to ShopInRelationshipModel object.

```dart
class ShopModel {
  final int? id;
  final int? adrnr;
  final int? industry;
  final String shop_name;
  final int? currency;

  const ShopModel({
    this.id,
    this.adrnr,
    required this.industry,
    required this.shop_name,
    required this.currency,
  });

  factory ShopModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ShopModel(
      id: json['id'] ?? '',
      adrnr: json['adrnr'] ?? null,
      industry: json['industry'] ?? 1,
      shop_name: json['shop_name'] ?? '',
      currency: json['currency_id'] ?? '',
    );
  }
```

```dart
class ShopInRelationshipModel {
  final int? id;
  final int? shop_id;
  final String? uid;
  final int relationship_type;
  final ShopModel? shop;

  const ShopInRelationshipModel({
    this.id,
    required this.shop_id,
    required this.uid,
    required this.relationship_type,
    required this.shop,
  });

  factory ShopInRelationshipModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ShopInRelationshipModel(
      uid: json['uid'] ?? '',
      shop_id: (json['shop_id']) ?? '',
      id: json['id'] ?? '',
      relationship_type: json['relationship_type'] ?? 1,
      shop: ShopModel.fromJson(json['shop']),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
List<ShopInRelationshipModel> shopInRelationshipList;

final response = await _supabase.client
          .from('shop_relationship')
          .select('*, shop(*)')
          .eq('uid', userId);

      //convert response to list of ShopInRelationshipModel. Here the error is coming
      shopInRelationshipList =
          response.map((e) => ShopInRelationshipModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Here is the sample response incase you need it.

```
response = [{id: 1, created_at: 2023-05-08T16:15:58.453985+00:00, shop_id: 11, uid: ac8ae335-2b10-47f3-8ad6-6d4c838439bf, relationship_type: 1, shop: {id: 11, created_at: 2023-05-08T16:15:34.876639+00:00, adrnr: null, industry: 1, shop_name: New Store, currency_id: 1}}, {id: 2, created_at: 2023-05-08T16:39:56+00:00, shop_id: 9, uid: ac8ae335-2b10-47f3-8ad6-6d4c838439bf, relationship_type: 1, shop: {id: 9, created_at: 2023-05-08T16:09:38.251026+00:00, adrnr: null, industry: 1, shop_name: ABC Store, currency_id: 1}}]
```

I am trying to convert the response from Supabase join query to `ShopInRelationshipModel` but I am receiving an error.

`'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ShopInRelationshipModel>`

Kindly help with how to convert response to `List<ShopInRelationshipModel>` object.

Comment: Try adding `as List<ShopInRelationshipModel>` after `.toList()`

Comment: Or try `cast<ShopInRelationshipModel>()` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/cast.html

Comment: @raw-chicken it didnot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `.cast<Model>()` to the list.

The code would look like this.

```
shopInRelationshipList = response
          .map((e) => ShopInRelationshipModel.fromJson(e))
          .toList()
          .cast<ShopInRelationshipModel>();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
final response = await _supabase.client
          .from('shop_relationship')
          .select('*, shop(*)')
          .eq('uid', userId);

  
      shopInRelationshipList =
          response.map<ShopInRelationshipModel>((e) => ShopInRelationshipModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Comment: same error, issue did not resolve.